# wpf drag and drop setter invoke in source

Tags: wpf, binding, drag-and-drop

I have a textbox like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtCondition" Text="{Binding Path=Name ,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

When I select the text in this textbox and drag it to somewhere the setter of the binded property in this textbox is automatically called, but I don't understand why :( .

Is it possible to turn it off somehow, that the wpf doesn't call the setter property in this case?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Regards,
Zoli

EDIT:

We have to do some hack here :) .

We create a bool variable in the viewModel. Set the bool variable true in the previewDrop event, and when the setter is called check this bool variable value. If it's true, do nothing in the setter, and set the bool variable to false.

Other way, you can check the stacktrace to find out where this setter is invoked :)

But I'm very curious why wpf calls the setter of the binded property in the source when we drop an item from it, so If somebody know this reason please inform us :) .

Answer (score 0):

The default binding behaviour of TextBoxes is to update when focus is lost, so when you drag away this is triggered. You could change the [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) of the binding to `Explicit` to avoid the automatic update but then of course you need to trigger the update manually at some time.

Comment: It won't works with explicit too :( . The setter invokes when I release the mousebutton with the dragged text.

Comment: Anyway after dropping, the focus already on the dragged text in the previous textbox.

Comment: Thanks, I'm waiting for it :)

Comment: I guess this has to do with the encapsulated implementation of the drag and drop functionality. I cannot think of a clean and easy way to avoid this right now. You could possibly try to disable the default drag and drop (which is not trival) and implement it manually without forcing the bindig updates.

Comment: Bad news :( . I hope there is an other way.

Comment: We have to do some hack here :) .
We create a bool variable in the viewModel. Set the bool variable in the previewDrop event, and when the setter is called check this bool variable value. If it's true, do nothing in the setter, and set the bool variable to false.

But I'm very curious why wpf calls the setter of the source control when we drop an item from it.

Comment: Other way, you can check the stacktrace to find out where this setter is invoked :) .

Comment: You might want to post your workarounds as an actual answer (as soon as you are allowed to if you cannot right now). Intercepting the setter sounds reasonable.